# Vue 3 Mutate Composition API state from external script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

### Forewords

In Option API, I was able to directly mutate instance `data` properties without losing any of reactivity. As described in [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data).

If you ask why, well not everything is written in Vue and there're cases where external JS libraries have to change certain value inside Vue instance.

For example:

```
document.app = createApp({
    components: {
        MyComponent, //MyComponent is a Option API
    }
})


//Somewhere else

<MyComponent ref="foo"/>
```

Then component state can be mutated as follow:

```
//Console:
document.app.$refs.foo.$data.message = "Hello world"
```

With the help of `ref`, regardless of component hiarchy, the state mutating process is kept simple as that.

### Question

Now in Composition API, I want to achieve the same thing, with setup script if it's possible.

When I do `console.log(document.app.$refs)`, I just only get `undefined` as returned result.

So let's say I have MyComponent:

```
<template>
    {{message}}
<template>

<script setup>
    const message = ref('Hello world');
</script>
```

How to mutate this child component state from external script? And via a `ref` preferably, if it's easier

Comment: Unless your case is exotic, this preferably should be done the opposite way, Vue app wraps around a script and interacts with it in some way - window event bus or else.

Comment: @EstusFlask JavaScript frameworks are known for having deeper and superior control. Thus having conflict with older libraries such as jQuery and wrapping Vue around cause them non functional. I wonder if event bus has that kind of compatibility issue?

Comment: Depends on the case. You can wrap any lib with a component, as long as they support manual init and disposal that can by synced with comp lifecycle, not just init once when a script is loaded. A lot of well-designed older libs do. As for compatibility, no issues https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refs that are exposed from setup function are automatically unwrapped, so a ref can't be changed as a property on component instance.

In order for a ref to be exposed to the outside, this needs to be explicitly done:

```
setup(props, ctx) {
   const message = ref('Hello world');

   ctx.expose({ message });

   return { message };
}
```

This is different in case of `script setup` because variables are exposed on a template but not component instance. As the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component) states:

> An exception here is that components using  are private by default: a parent component referencing a child component using  won't be able to access anything unless the child component chooses to expose a public interface using the defineExpose macro

It should be:

```
<script setup>
...
const message = ref('Hello world');
defineExpose({ message });
</script>
```

Comment: `defineExpose` looks like the what I need. Although I've to "dig" deeply in bunch of nested property. `defineExpose` seems to be working without breaking reactivity: `document.app._instance.refs.foo.message = "New message"`. I will update asap

Comment: This is a bad practice. Unless you hack into somebody else's app, you need to just design component public api the way it's comfortable for the intended use from the outside, i.e. top-level comp should have `updateFooMessage` method.

Comment: I hate to say but yep. It's bad practice and I don't recommend no one to follow this way. The project was written in legacy code base so I need something to refer to Vue instance (`app` in this case). I will try another way if possible

Comment: Update for those still struggling: While changing data the way mentioned in my first comment may work in development environment, it won't work in production. It's better to keep data encapsulated and follow suggested way. I finally chose to use window messaging events and write top-comp custom API to receive and mutate data.